# How to pick(choose) multiple images using camera API at the same time in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to choose or pick  multiple images at the same time in `phonegap camera API` when using **`Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI.`** I am able to pick only one images at a time. I am able to pick multiple files(including txt,pdf..) in sdcard using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868323/how-to-pickchoose-multiple-files-at-the-same-time-in-phonegap). So i want same like for images.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                    }, onFail, {
    quality : 50,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
```

My cordova version 3.3, Jquery Mobile 1.3.2.

Please suggest any plugins are available to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [Cordova multiple image selector plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) to choose multiple image at a time. It is good plugin for choose  multiple images.

Download the above `plugin and copy paste the java classes`. Set the required `permission`. Don't forget to copy the `res folder` just copy and paste in your res folder.

Inside `assets/www` create imagepicker.js copy and paste the dowloaded imagepicker.js

In your `index.html` set like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imagepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady(){

        window.imagePicker.getPictures(
                function(results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        alert('Image URI: ' + results[i]);

// read file type and size and file name like below(in comment)

/* window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(results[i], function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) { 
            alert(fileEntry.name);
            alert(fileObj.size);
            alert(fileObj.type);
        }); 

    }, function (error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        });*/
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                }
            );

    }
    </script>
```

**`Note: This should work only cordova 3.0 and above and android 4.0 and above`**

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to set which folder to open OR display an interface with the various folders for the user?

Answer (score 1):

Open CameraLauncher.java file and replace these lines

```
String resizePath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/resize.jpg";
this.callbackContext.success("file://" + resizePath + "?" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

to

```
String resizePath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/resize"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
this.callbackContext.success("file://" + resizePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x=0;
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI)
{
    x++;
    // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
    console.log(imageURI);
 alert(imageURI);
    // Get image handle
    //
    var y = 'smallImage'+x;
    var smallImage = document.getElementById(y);
    alert(smallImage);
 smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  
    // Show the captured photo
    // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    //var fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    //fso.CopyFile("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI,"file:///storage/sdcard/DCIM/");
      
    alert(smallImage.src)
}
```

where x is the loop for doing the multiple image from camera as well as from photogallery