# Opening the pdf from mulitple pdf readers - for android?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

How to write the code for file chooser in phonegap ?. My requirement is like if the User contain multiple pdf reader then we need show the list which the user contain. if he has only one then open the pdf.

Comment: Maybe this can help you?




  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868323/how-to-pickchoose-multiple-files-at-the-same-time-in-phonegap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868323/how-to-pickchoose-multiple-files-at-the-same-time-in-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

There are a few file opener plugins
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/fr.smile.cordova.fileopener

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.vaadin.alump.openfile

and even inAppBrowser might work with _system param:
 window.open('path/to/yourFile/file.pdf', '_system');

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser